# Convert multiple lines of text to Array

Tags: text

So I have a really long text document (10 million lines) and I want to convert that document to an array.
For example, my text document is:

```
a
b
c
```

and I want to convert this to:

`["a","b","c"]`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

First read document as plain text and
use `split` method with split character **`'\n'`**. This will split your document on new lines.